# ffmpeg not listing audio output device

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, audio-recording

I'm running the following code to get all the devices but I'm not getting any of my audio output devices.

> ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

[image: ffmpeg listed devices]

I'm looking forward recording from the speaker or headset.

Comment: `-dshow` only supports input devices. afaik ffmpeg deos not support any windows audio output device

Comment: @kesh Do you know if it's possible to record windows audio output device with ffmpeg?

Comment: You need to use a realtek loopback device, which I believe only becomes available if you install a driver from realtek and not windows' default.

Comment: You can also use [this project](https://github.com/rdp/virtual-audio-capture-grabber-device) on Windows. After installing it, you should see `virtual-audio-capturer` in the list, which will contain computer audio output.